# Robotic Arm Controlled via Python

Tags: python, robotics

I want to improve my programing skills and I thought that to start using physical programing(if that's even a thing) could possible be a great way to do improve it. But I don't know where to start.

I want to be able to build and control a robotic arm. and program it to do specifc task, my ultimate goal is to make it paint something.

Where can I start? Should I build my own robotic arm or it's too hard for a newb and I should buy one insted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would certainly look in to Arduino for this before going with Python. You can get parts for the arm at a variety of online retailers (adafruit and sparkfun are good). You can find numerous books on Arduino at your local bookstore or Amazon.

Comment: A friend told me about Arduino but I would like to program in Python since i'm already familiar with it. Anyway I'll take a look in it, thanks.

Comment: You can certainly use Python on a computer to generate commands, crunch data, etc. But to actually control the arm, you will need to use something like Arduino. The only way around that that I can see would be soldering a usb connector to your robotic arm and writing a driver yourself. 

There are probably ways somewhat similar to that that I am unaware of, but I doubt they are much simpler.